# data type(s) of the type parameters ) in method cannot be inferred from these arguments

Tags: database, vb.net, linq, variables, range

I have the following code which is throwing an error on the submit line.  It says that `data type(s) of the type parameters ) in method cannot be inferred from these arguments`.  As I have (I think) explicitly stated the data types surely it should work.  The `userID` is being taken directly from the database through another query.

```
Dim compulsoryModule = (From mods In db.Modules
                                Join deg In db.Degrees On mods.Degree_code Equals deg.Degree_code
                                Where deg.Degree_code = degree And mods.Compulsory = True And mods.Level = 1
                                Select mods.Module_code)

        Dim year = (From mods1 In db.Modules
                    Join deg1 In db.Degrees On mods1.Degree_code Equals deg1.Degree_code
                    Where deg1.Degree_code = degree And mods1.Compulsory = True And mods1.Level = 1
                    Select mods1.Year)

        Dim semester = (From mods In db.Modules
                        Join deg In db.Degrees On mods.Degree_code Equals deg.Degree_code
                         Where deg.Degree_code = degree And mods.Compulsory = True And mods.Level = 1
                      Select mods.Semester)

Dim take As New Take With _
            {.User_Number = userId, _
             .Degree_code = degree, _
             .Module_code = compulsoryModule, _
             .Year = years, _
             .Semester = semesters}

        db.Takes.InsertAllOnSubmit(take)
```

It is the last line that gives the error

Answer (score 1):

Ok fixed this.  The problem was that I was returning multiple records and trying to enter them as one new record, causing the error.  I amended my submit section to be a for loop to my code to iterate through the results and add them individually.  The loop I used was:

```
 For Each moduleCode As String In compulsoryModules

            Dim take As New Take With _
                {.User_Number = userId, _
                 .Degree_code = degree, _
                 .Module_code = moduleCode, _
                 .Year = years, _
                 .Semester = semesters}

            db.Takes.InsertOnSubmit(take)
```

Hope this helps someone else.